# only accepting letters and spaces, numbers and spaces, and letters and numbers with spaces in different boxes

Tags: javascript, regex

I can't figure out why these regular expressions aren't working correctly.

I need 3 different types of expression checks, but the methods aren't working fully like they are suppose to.  They work "partially" as shown in example for #output2 where the response turns out to be an invalid, but it doesn't catch the first one.  I'm assuming there's something small i'm missing?

I'm trying to do the following validations...

**EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION SORRY!**

var letters - should only accept letters with absolutely no digits or special characters, but still allow for spaces but only a max of 1 space (so no double spaces) and can't lead or end with a space.  An empty string should still pass as being valid.

var digits - same as var letters, but digits only with no letters with no special characters. No leading or training spaces or double spaces anywhere. Blank entry is still valid.

var lettersDigits - only allow letters and digits with no special characters. No leading or training spaces or double spaces anywhere. Blank entry is still valid.

https://jsfiddle.net/umdhh5fb/

```
var value = '2 a s 2 s 2 a';
var valueInValid = 'a a a a a 2'
var valueDigits = '12321 asda 12312  2';

var letters = /([a-zA-Z]+\s)*[a-zA-Z]+$/; // only letters with no more than 2 spaces
var digits = /[\d+\s]*[\d]+$/; // only digits with no more than 2 spaces

var lettersDigits = /[a-zA-Z\d+\s]*[a-zA-Z\d]+$/; // digits and letters allowed no special characters no more than 2 spaces

if (letters.test(value) == false) {
$("#output").text("invalid");
} else {
$("#output").text("valid");
}

if (letters.test(valueInValid) == false) {
$("#output2").text("invalid");
} else {
$("#output2").text("valid");
}


if (digits.test(valueDigits) == false) {
$("#output3").text("invalid");
} else {
$("#output3").text("valid");
}


if (lettersDigits.test(value) == false) {
$("#output4").text("invalid");
} else {
$("#output4").text("valid");
}


<div id="output"></div> /* returns valid */
<div id="output2"></div> /* returns invalid */
<div id="output3"></div> /* returns valid */
<div id="output4"></div> /* returns valid */
```

Comment: This is Javascript, not HTML.

Comment: None of your regular expressions are anchored to the beginning of the string with `^`. So they just test the end of the value, not the whole value.

Comment: I do not understand fully what is the intention of each of your regexps. Could you explain exactly what pattern you want to validate? (Example: "A sequence of letters, followed by one or two spaces, and so on").

Comment: Your comments all say "no more than 2 spaces". But there's nothing in any of the regular expressions that limits the number of spaces. Also, why do you have `+` inside the character classes, like `[\d+\s]`? That allows digits, spaces, and the `+` sign.

Comment: I was trying to explain exactly which each one is suppose to do do that after each reg expression I wrote I guess I should of been more clear sorry.  @Barmar to my knowledge [\d+\s] would allow any digit to happen one or more times followed by a single space?  Did i understand that wrong?

Comment: Yes, you understand wrong. `[...]` matches a single character that's one of the characters inside it. `+` has no special meaning inside square brackets.

Comment: You're thinking of `(\d+\s)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the anchor `^` to the beginning of your regular expressions, so that it matches the whole value, not just the end of the value.

To make something optional, follow it with `?`. To allow at most one space between things, make an expression that ends with space optional. And to allow an empty input, make everything between `^` and `$` optional.

```js
var value = '2 a s 2 s 2 a';
var valueInValid = 'a a a a a 2'
var valueDigits = '12321 asda 12312  2';

var letters = /^(([a-z]+\s)?[a-z]+)?$/i; // only letters with no more than 1 spaces
var digits = /^((\d+\s)?\d+)?$/; // only digits with no more than 1 spaces

var lettersDigits = /^(([a-z\d]+\s)?[a-z\d]+)?$/i; // digits and letters allowed no special characters no more than 1 spaces

if (letters.test(value) == false) {
  $("#output").text("invalid");
} else {
  $("#output").text("valid");
}

if (letters.test(valueInValid) == false) {
  $("#output2").text("invalid");
} else {
  $("#output2").text("valid");
}

if (digits.test(valueDigits) == false) {
  $("#output3").text("invalid");
} else {
  $("#output3").text("valid");
}

if (lettersDigits.test(value) == false) {
  $("#output4").text("invalid");
} else {
  $("#output4").text("valid");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
<div id="output2"></div>
<div id="output3"></div>
<div id="output4"></div>
```

Comment: Barmar I apologize, but I left out that the var's being blank should still be considered valid.  Which is why I thought i had to leave out the ^ to indicate they were all optional.  I understand now that its about the * but the solutions I have orignally still don't work.  I'll better explain

Comment: If you want to make the whole thing optional, put `(...)?` around it: `^(...)?$`.

Comment: Or you can change `+` to `*`, since that matches 0 or more times, instead of 1 or more times.

Comment: I updated my original to try and better explain what I was going for.  Very sorry for all the confusion.  I did a tutorial on regular expressions and it didn't mention that i couldn't do + inside [...] to mean one or more repetitions.

Comment: I understand now.  Thank you very much, any way you can update your answer to the fixed version so I can mark it as answer for future people?  I see now in other posts where it was answered I didn't read comments section and they had marked answers correctly when they weren't updated to the correct solution.  Thank you very much! I learned alot